# How to show results of a query inside the django admin?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I want to display a result of queries in my `django admin`. In my django admin, at the `MyModel` page, it lists all the tuples as it should. But I also want to display some more results in a separate block in that same page, and these results would be the output of some predefined query.

**What I have tried so far:**

- Read the `django docs` for adding a custom view in admin, tried it, but it doesnt seem to do what I want.
- Tried over-riding `queryset`. But then it modifies the results that normally are on display. I do not want this. I want to display all the tuples and then a set of tuples separately in that same page in a different block.
- Tried solutions of other similar questions at SO. But again not what I want.

**What I am currently looking into at this moment:**

- django-admin-tools : Reading its documentation. Hoping something comes up.

Please help me. I am clueless.

Comment: Are your queries based on certain objects in the admin? You could write [a django action with an intermediate page](http://www.jpichon.net/blog/2010/08/django-admin-actions-and-intermediate-pages/) that displays the query

Comment: No no. I will query based on a certain condition. I will query on the same model itself.